# Webpack Dynamic Require

Tags: webpack

I have some modules named using this convention `framework-{function}` and I require them dynamically.

```
init(name, options) {
    let plugin = require(`framework-${name}`)(this, options);
    this.registerPlugin(name, plugin);
}
```

Webpack generates this code when I use development mode in webpack config. It complains `Cannot find module framework-db` even if it does exist in my `node_modules`.

```
/***/ "./node_modules/framework sync recursive ^framework\\-.*$":
/*!*****************************************************!*\
  !*** ./node_modules/framework sync ^framework\-.*$ ***!
  \*****************************************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

    eval("function webpackEmptyContext(req) {\n\tvar e = new Error('Cannot find module \"' + req + '\".');\n\te.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND';\n\tthrow e;\n}\nwebpackEmptyContext.keys = function() { return []; };\nwebpackEmptyContext.resolve = webpackEmptyContext;\nmodule.exports = webpackEmptyContext;\nwebpackEmptyContext.id = \"./node_modules/framework sync recursive ^framework\\\\-.*$\";\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///./node_modules/framework_sync_^framework\\-.*$?");

/***/ }),
```

If I hard code it,

```
init(name, options) {
    let plugin = require(`framework-db`)(this, options);
    this.registerPlugin(name, plugin);
}
```

it works.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your `name` variable is not known at the time webpack make the build?

If it's so, you could try to insert a string literal in the path of the module, for webpack to create a context module, for exemple something like:

`let plugin = require('node_modules/framework-' + name)(this, options);`

It's documented here, in "require with expression" section:
https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/

Be carefull, try to have the most specific path in this string literal, because, as specified in docs:

> This means dynamic requires are supported but will cause all possible modules to be included in the bundle.

so making `node_modules` the directory of this context module is probably not a good idea unless you find any workaround.